# how to call calc() function from main.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create the calculation function like

```
def calc():
  #Body of calculation 
  NOW = datetime.now() #shows undefined
  ...
  DR = os.getcwd() #shows undefined
  ..
  for j in ROW: #shows undefined
  #Assume Adding two variables like (a+b)
  #Body of calculation ENDS
```

I don't know how to call the function in my main.py. Actions that I need to perform in main.py is to call the function and clear the undefined objects in Add_Func.py

```
import os 
from Add_Func import calc #Import the Add_Func.py file
from datetime import datetime
import DB_Connectivity as DB #Import the .py file
CONN = DB.connect()
CUR = CONN.cursor()
TB = input('Enter the table name:')
SQL = """select * from %s""" %(TB)
CUR.execute(SQL)
ROW = CUR.fetchall()
```

Kindly suggest some code to resolve the script.

Comment: Please update your question showing how you expect to call your `calc()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that all three files (main.py, Add_Func.py and DB_Connectivity.py) are in the same directory, it should work to `from Add_Func import calc` and `import DB_Connectivity as DB` without any changes. You should import `datetime` and `os` where you're gonna use them though:

main.py

```
from Add_Func import calc #Import the Add_Func.py file

import DB_Connectivity as DB #Import the .py file
CONN = DB.connect()
CUR = CONN.cursor()
TB = input('Enter the table name:')
SQL = """select * from %s""" %(TB)
CUR.execute(SQL)
ROW = CUR.fetchall()
```

Add_Func.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

def calc(ROW):
  #Body of calculation 
  NOW = datetime.now() #shows undefined

  DR = os.getcwd() #shows undefined

  for j in ROW: #shows undefined
    pass
    #Assume Adding two variables like (a+b)
    #Body of calculation ENDS
```

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestions. @TelmoTrooper, May I know how could I pass the arg (ROW). Still the ROW is undefined name warning in Add.Func file.

Comment: @SathishJay I just updated my answer. Change `def calc():` to `def calc(ROW):` and when you call `calc`, pass `ROW` as an argument.

Comment: Here's a useful reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. You want to tell your main script to look at the location of your `Add_Func.py` file by adding it to `sys.path`, which is basically a list of where Python looks for modules.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path/of/your/add_func.py/file/goes/here")
from Add_Func import calc
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have the following file

**calc.py**

```
#calc.py
def add(x, y):
  return x + y
```

There's two scenarios to import that file into your modules

## Simple Folder Structure

Suppose you have that folder structure

**Folder Structure**

```
src
 |--main.py
 |--calc.py
```

In order to call a function inside calc you just have to import into your main using import

**main.py**

```
#main.py
from calc import add

add(1, 1)
```

## Nested Folder Structure

In that scenario you must tell the interpreter to look inside that folder when searching for custom modules. So suppose that file structure

**Folder Structure**

```
src
 |--main.py
 |--lib
     |--calc.py
```

Your main should be like that:

**main.py**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))

from lib import calc

calc.add(2, 3)
```

## Best Practices

A better way to do that is to organize your folder structure like that

**Folder Structure**

```
src
 |--__init__.py
 |--main.py
 |--lib
     |--calc.py
     |--__init__.py
```

And then do all your path appending in `src/__init__.py`. And use `lib/__init__.py` to control which functions you'll make public outside the module.

Example:

**src/__init__.py**

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))
```

**lib/__init__.py**

```
from .calc import add
```

**lib/calc.py**

```
def add(x, y):
  return x + y

def myCustomPrivateFunc(x):
  pass
```

**src/main.py**

```
from lib import add

add(1, 2)
```

Comment: Good method. I like how your `sys.path` relies on the structure around the main file, rather than absolute paths (that will then be wrong when moving between computers).